# inserting a convertage percentage into a database

Tags: python, sqlite

right my aim for this piece is to get the printed value into a database but on query from terminal the database returns the floating point not the printed value is there a way to force this to pass over to the database. 
here is my code

```
def getCpuLoad():
   """
   Returns the cpu load as a value from the interval [0.0, 1.0]
   """
   dt = list(deltaTime(INTERVAL))
   idle_time = float(dt[3])
   total_time = sum(dt)
   load = 1-(idle_time/total_time)
   return load



def diskspace():
  stats = os.statvfs('/opt')
  freespace = stats.f_bavail * stats.f_frsize
  freespace / 1048576
  return freespace

while True:
  print time.strftime("%A, %B, %d, %Y, %H, %M"),"CPU usage=%.2f%%" % (getCpuLoad()*100) 
  cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable (Date, Cpu) VALUES (?,?)''',(today, getCpuLoad()))
  print time.strftime("%A, %B, %d, %Y, %H, %M"), diskspace()
  cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable (Date, free) VALUES (?,?)''',(today,diskspace()))
```

cursor.commit() 
as it can be seen, I do the rounding of the floating point at print but as said above it only inserts it without the conversion. can anyone help please be clear as i am still learning both. python and sqlite3.

Comment: Is the problem that you _think_ you are storing say `12.34` into `mytable.Cpu` and when you inspect it, you see say `12.3399921` ?  BTW what is the definition of mytable?

Comment: yes when i inspect it returns a decimal floating point. mytable is just a name for the table in the database where cpu is the column

Answer (score 0):

For numeric data, SQLlite3 supports either **integer** (stored on 1, 2, 4, 6 or 8 bytes)  or real (stored as 8-byte [**IEEE floating point number**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).

The Cpu column appears to be at the moment a REAL type, and when inspecting values in this column you don't see neat numbers with exactly two digits after the decimal point.  This is because of the following two reasons:

- the number, initially produced by `getCpuLoad()` was computed to the fullest precision allowed by Python floating point arithmetic.
- Anyway even if you were to `round()` that number at some point in your logic and depending which program you use to inspect this value, the floating format is such that some values will still look approximate (e.g. say showing  `13.5999999` where you'd be expecting a nice `13.6`)

In other words:  you can modify `getCpuLoad()`'s last but one line to read

```
  load = round(1-(idle_time/total_time), 2)
```

i.e. rounding the return value to two decimal digits, but, depending how you inspect these values, do not expect that they'll "look" systemtically with 2 an exactly 2 digit after the decimal point.

Rounding the values explicitly, however will "uniformize" your data, in a sense that whereby previously two different records in mytable could have values like, say,  `12.3456781` and `12.3489121`, now these two values would be the exact same, `12.35` (even though it may look as `12.34999999` when inspected with some database tool.

Alternatively you could consider storing these values as integers, with a implicit factor of 100, i.e. storing,say,  `1234` in lieu of `12.34`.  If you do so of course you will need to divide the value by 100 when using or displaying it.
Yet another possible storage type would be to store the value as a SQLite TEXT type, but this would be rather inconvenient as you'd need to convert the value (with all the processing cost and the exceptions associated with ASCII-to-Numeric conversion) each time you need it.

As to conclude, and if you are so inclined you can read
[***"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg to understand, among other things,  why these rounding errors come to be.